# Have problem in Drop button for Selecting year range for Normal Flask python program

Tags: python, html, flask

I have written a program which is built on flask app this program is mainly built to multiply the data it will take the user data randomly print the data what ever user want 5k.. 10k..so on after that I want to do it through web page so I used Flask there I have added the file select (to browse CSV file) and record count where user specify how much data they want to generate and very important part where I'm stuck that is "from year" and "to year" which I'm doing through JavaScript in HTML file this is a drop down button which have a specified years

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> upload </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

            for(var i=1970; i<=2018; i++){
                var fromYearSelect = document.getElementById("fromYear");
                var toYearSelect = document.getElementById("toYear");

                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
                fromYearSelect.options.add(option);
                option.text = i;
                option.value = i;


                var option2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
                toYearSelect.options.add(option2);
                option2.text = i;
                option2.value = i;
            }
        });
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class = "mx-auto" style="width:500px;">
        <h1>Large Data Generation</h1>      

      </div>     
    </div>

    <form id = "upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="file-selector">
            <strong>Input File: </strong>
            <input id="source_fileName" type="file" name="source_fileName" accept="csv/*" multiple style="
    margin-left: 30px;"> 
        </div>
        <br></br>

        <div id="div_records">
            <strong>Record Count: </strong>
            <input id="records" type="text" name="records" value="1000" >
            <br> <br> <br>
            <strong>From Year: </strong>
            <select id="fromYear" name="fromYear" style="margin-left: 25px;"></select>
            <!--  <input type="month" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" multiple style="margin-left: 20px;" >  -->

            <strong style="margin-left:20px">To Year: </strong>

            <select id="toYear" name="toYear" style="margin-left: 5px;"></select>
            <!--  <input type="month" id="toDate" name="toDate" multiple style="margin-left: 40px;"> -->



        </div>
        <br></br><br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Manufacture Data" id="upload-button"  >
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

This program works very well when I select years range less 5 if I select more than 5 it's not working.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import csv
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,Response, redirect, make_response
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

tempFile =""
#defined the flask route
@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Loading the root file")
    return render_template("uploadDataManf.html")

@app.route("/uploadDataManf", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'metadata/')
    print("target-",target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    global recordCount
    recordCount = int(request.values.get("records"))
    print("recordCount-",recordCount)

    global fromYear
    fromYear = int(request.values.get("fromYear"))
    print("From Year - " + request.values.get("fromYear"));

    global toYear
    toYear = int(request.values.get("toYear"))
    print("To Year - " + request.values.get("toYear"));

    for file in request.files.getlist("source_fileName"):
        print("file-",file)
        filename = file.filename
        print("filename-",filename)

        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print("destination-",destination)
        file.save(destination)
        print("file>",file)
        global tempFile
        tempFile = destination
        print("tempFile - " + tempFile)

    #define global scope and reference it
        global destination_fileName
        destination_fileName = request.form.get('target_fileName')
        print("destination_fileName",destination_fileName)

    return redirect("/compute", )

def segment():
    number= recordCount
    a = number
    n = 12
    assert a >= n >= 1

    seg = []
    for idx in range(n-1):
        # Number between 1 and a
        # minus the current total so we don't overshoot
        # minus 1 for each number that hasn't been picked
        # so they can all be nonzero
        seg.append(randint(1,a-sum(seg)-n+idx))
    seg.append(a-sum(seg))
    random.shuffle(seg)
    print("NumberOfseg-",seg)
    return seg

@app.route("/compute")
def compute():
    Year_Array=[]
    for val in range(fromYear, toYear+1):
        Year_Array.append(val)

    print("Year Array - ",Year_Array)

    Month_Array=['Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

    final_Array=[]
    p=0
    global recordCount
    recordCount = recordCount / len(Year_Array)

    df = pd.read_csv(tempFile)


    temp = df.iloc[1]
    print(temp)
    #print(temp.loc)
    #print(temp['Asset_Id'])

    for p in range(0, len(Year_Array), 1):
        c = 0
        # Regenerate segments
        seg = segment()

        for i in range(0,len(seg), 1):
            h=seg[i]


            for j in range(0, int(h) , 1):
                num=randint(0, len(df)-1)
                row=df.iloc[num]

                final_Array.append(((Year_Array[p], Month_Array[c],row.get("Asset_Id"),row.get("Asset Family"),row.get("Asset Name"),row.get("Location"),row.get("Asset Component"),row.get("Keywords"),row.get("Conditions"),row.get("Parts"))))
            c += 1

    data = pd.DataFrame(final_Array)
    data['SR_ID'] = 'SR_' + pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(data.index) + 1)).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
    data.columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Asset_Id ', 'Asset Family', 'Asset Name', 'Location', 'Asset Component', 'Keywords', 'Conditions', 'Parts','SR_ID']
    result = data[['SR_ID','Year', 'Month', 'Asset_Id ', 'Asset Family', 'Asset Name', 'Location', 'Asset Component', 'Keywords', 'Conditions', 'Parts']]
    print("result-",result)
    resp = make_response(result.to_csv(index=False,))
    resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=OutputData.csv"
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"    
    return resp  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Actually I know where is the problem it's in function `compute` where I have:

```
global recordCount
recordCount = recordCount / len(Year_Array)
```

If I remove this it will resolve my problem but after that it will not generate data according to the user it will multiply the data with years range that I don't want I want that if I select in record count 1k means it should print only 1k not more than that.

Sample input of csv file:

```
Asset_Id    Asset Family    Asset Name  Location    Asset Component Keywords    Conditions  Parts
1           Haptic Analyser HAL1        Zenoa       Tetris Measuring Unit   Measurement Inaccuracy, Mirror Angle Skewed Alignment - Lower Axis - positive angle  Tetris Controller, Measurement Unit, Processor, Signal Emitter,  TDU
1           Haptic Analyser HAL1        Zenoa       Micro Pressure Platform Low air pressure,   Pressure - Fluctuating  Measuring Faces, Cycle Timer, Pressure Simulator, Platform Unit,  Sensometer, Pressure Release, 
1           Haptic Analyser HAL1        Technopolis Rotation Chamber    Rotation Chamber Intermittent Slowdown  Current - Fluctuating   Anti-Rotation Pin, Springs, Gyroscope, Joiner, Separator, Sealant, Chamber Enclosure, Mount Unit
1           Haptic Analyser HAL1        Technopolis Mirror Lens Combinator  Mirror Angle Skewed,    Alignment - Mid Axis - negative angle   "Mirror Unit, Lens Unit, 


2           Hyperdome Inspector HISP1   Technopolis Turbo Quantifier    Quantifier output Drops Intermittently  Pressure - Low  Gas Generator, Quantifier Processing Unit, Turbo Generator, Backup Unit, Turbo Drive
2           Hyperdome Inspector HISP1   Technopolis Generator   Generator Power Failure,    Vibration - 135% above threshold    Generator Armature, Generator Unit, Measurement Gauge, Pressure Gauge, Temperature Gauge,  
2           Hyperdome Inspector HISP1   Technopolis High Frequency Emulator Emulator Frequency Drop Speed at entrance - Fluctuating Amplifier, Oscillator, Frequency Emulator, Display Unit, High Frequency Simululator, Drum,  
2           Hyperdome Inspector HISP1   Zenoa   Center Stage    Stage not Balanced  Vibration - 110% above threshold    Stage Support, Stage Enclosure, Stage Balancer, Alignment Unit, Line Control,
```

Comment: **Guys please don't down grade the question please tell me if you don't understand anything..**

Comment: can you please tell why are you using these many global  variables?

Comment: i think you should use `session` to store your variables instead of making them global

Comment: Actucally my in program i'm doing lots of things don't know efficent way of doing this .... @Nihal

Comment: did u got the problem why not able to generate data for more than 5 years? @Nihal will use all global var in seesion but i don't it will help me to get it

Comment: what type of file you are trying to upload?

Comment: its a csv file which contain 1300 data which im generting very large data randomly..

Comment: can you provide some sample of csv? in your question.

Comment: Added the Sample data @Nihal its really big that to paste here hope now u can get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185106/discussion-between-nihal-and-snehil-singh).

Comment: @Nihal let me know if  you available